# Is there a name for a non-great-circle?

Tags: geometry

The intersection of a sphere and a plane which passes through the center of that sphere is called a great circle. Is there a name for the intersection of a sphere and a plane which does not pass through the center of the sphere? Of course, like a great circle, it is a circle, but I'm wondering if there is any special terminology that would indicate its relation to the sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: sensibly enough, it's called a [*small circle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere).

Comment: I was hoping for "OK circle" :-(